# Obtener Fecha/Hora del Sistema HTML o Php

Tags: php, html

Como Obtengo autoaticaente la hora del sistema sin que el usuario Interactue?

```
echo"<td>Fecha de Entrega <input type=date name=fecha_entrega size=10 value=\"".@$fecha_entrega."\"</td>";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eso necesitas establecer las zona horaria con [date_default_timezone_set()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php), de esta forma:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Melbourne');
$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());
```

Aquí tienes el listado de [zonas horarias](http://php.net/manual/es/timezones.php)

Answer (score 2):

La cuestión es que querrás que la hora se actualice cada segundo (supongo), mostrándolo como un reloj.

Lo mejor sería hacerlo del lado del cliente, usando la librería `moment`, en Javascript.

Para presentar los nombres de días/meses en castellano, puedes incluir la librería **[`moment-with-locale.js`](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.js)**

Pones esto al principio y te mostrará los nombres en castellano:

```
   moment.locale('es');
```

Veamos un ejemplo, usando Javascript puro:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    moment.locale('es');
    var upDate = function() {
      var elFecha = document.querySelector("#fecha");
      var elHora = document.querySelector("#hora");
      var nowDate = moment(new Date());
      elHora.textContent = nowDate.format('HH:mm:ss');
      elFecha.textContent =
      nowDate.format('dddd DD [de] MMMM [de] YYYY ');
    }
    setInterval(upDate, 1000);
});
```

```css
#fecha {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

<div class="nowDateTime">
  <p>
    <span id="fecha"></span><br />
    <span id="hora"></span>
  </p>
</div>
```

La librería `moment.js`, tiene más posibilidades interesantes y las puedes descubrir [en su sitio web](https://momentjs.com).