# Como puedo mostrar en el input la hora real del seridor en php.?

Tags: php, javascript, html

> Asi tengo mi input. Ya capture la hora, pero quisiera que la hora sea dinamica no estatico, que funciones de corrido los minuteros y segunderos..

```
<td>HORA: </td>
<td>
  <script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
    <div class="nowDateTime">
      <p>    
        <input id="p1" name="xhora" class="form-control"  readonly="readonly" autofocus="" required="" step="1">
        </input>
```

[image: Asi la tengo en el input del modal]

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
moment.locale('es');
var upDate = function() {
  var xhora = document.querySelector("#p1");
  var nowDate = moment(new Date());
  xhora.textContent = nowDate.format('HH:mm:ss');
}
setInterval(upDate, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Ya logre capturar la hora actual,pero lo que necesito es que funcione como un reloj digital, en el input ya que voy a controlar producciones, y al registrar me guarde los minutos o segundos en tiempo real. Ahora mismo para actualizar mi horario debo actualizar la pagina con el formulario ya que no es dinamico la hora , el minuto y el segundo. Gracias.

Comment: Para eso puedes usar `moment` es una librería Javascript  [aquí hay un ejemplo exacto de lo que quieres](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/209844/29967). Además tiene la ventaja de que trabaja **del lado del cliente, liberando así al servidor**, pues mantener la hora actualizada desde el servidor te va a costar estar enviando cada segundo una petición al servidor. Si en tu sitio hay al mismo tiempo 10 mil usuarios conectados son 10,000 peticiones x segundo, si hay 400 mil usuarios, 400 mil peticiones por segundo. Esa es la diferencia en este caso entre el cliente y el servidor.

Comment: <span  name="xhora" id="p1" class="form-control"  autofocus="" ></span>   ,tengo otro problema , ya logre mostrar el reloj, pero ahora no me inserta usando <span> no halla xhora, pero si pongo input si me inserta, pero no me muestra el reloj.

Comment: No, desde JS puedes obtener lo mismo que te muestra el span haciendo algo así: `moment()`, esto te da la fecha y hora completa y si solo quieres parte de la fecha lo puedes extraer también. Prueba esto y verás: `console.log(moment());` o `console.log(moment().format("YYYYMMDD"));` o cualquier otro formato de los explicados en la página de ellos.

Comment: Tengo un archivo js aparte y otro lado mi html. en html tengo los input, en el js utilizo la funcion de moment() y lo llamo en el html con <span> hasta ahi todo bien, funciona bien el reloj digital. pero al insertar hay un error, y no inserta.  si cambio span por input, inserta correctamente pero, no muestra el reloj. Tengo que mostrar en el formulario el reloj en ejecucion y insertar hasta que haga clic en insertar.

Comment: Arriba actualice mi codigo.

Comment: Si quieres enviar la fecha y hora actual al servidor para insertar puedes crear una variable en Javascript, por ejemplo: `var thisMoment=moment();` y enviar `thisMoment` junto con los demás datos al servidor. `thisMoment` tendrá exactamente lo mismo que estarás viendo en el `span`

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. Ya solucione todo.