# fecha y hora de bienvenida con php

Tags: php

trato de crear un saludo con php
pero en el codigo me manda buenas tardes
se sopene que se ejecuta con un else if
mientras pasa por las horas pero se queda en buenas tardes siendo de mañana

```
<?php 
  // Formato 24 horas (de 1 a 24) 
  $hora = date('G'); if (($hora >= 0) AND ($hora < 6)) 
  { 
    $mensaje = "Buena madrugada"; 
  } 
  else if (($hora >= 6) AND ($hora < 12)) 
  { 
    $mensaje = "Buenos dias"; 
  } 
  else if (($hora >= 12) AND ($hora < 18)) 
  { 
    $mensaje = "Buenas tardes"; 
  } 
  else
  { 
  $mensaje = "Buenas noches"; 
  } 
 echo '$mensaje'
?>
```

Comment: ¿Ya verificaste el valor que estas asignando a `$hora`? Te recomiendo hacer `var_dump($hora)` para corroborar el valor y ver el por que de la salida que mencionas. Saludos.

Comment: muestra string(2) "16"

Comment: La hora estaría según la zona horaria del servidor que no será por lo general la misma del cliente. Para saber la fecha/hora del cliente tendrías que hacerlo con JavaScript.

Comment: ¿Y qué hora es en tu país?, la función date toma la hora en tu servidor, a menos que la cambies o especifiques una zona horaria diferente. Saludos.

Comment: [Aquí un ejemplo muy simple](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/209844/29967) usando `moment.js` la mejor biblioteca (hiper ligera) para trabajar con fechas/horas del lado del cliente.

Answer (score 0):

con un CASE me ha funcionado de manera correcta con tu ejemplo. Espero te sirva. Saludos.

```html
<?php
$hora = date('G'); 
switch ($hora) {
   case (($hora >= 6) AND ($hora < 12)):
        $mensaje = "Buenos dias";
    echo $mensaje;
         break;
   case (($hora >= 12) AND ($hora < 18)):
         $mensaje = "Buenas tardes"; 
    echo $mensaje;
         break;
   case (($hora >= 0) AND ($hora < 6)):
         $mensaje = "Buena madrugada"; 
    echo $mensaje;
         break;
}
?>
```

Comment: No creo que el problema sean del OP sean los `IF`, sino la forma de obtener la hora. Saludos.

Comment: Acabo de leer lo de la zona horaria, es cierto lo que decis, disculpa. De todas manera puede llegar a servirle el CASE. Saludos

Comment: Si, tanto tu código como el del OP funcionan bien, bueno, en el del OP habría que quitar las comillas del último echo, pero el problema va más por el lado de la zona horaria, igualmente creo que A. Cedano tiene razón en cuanto a la parte de mejor utilizar JS para obtener la hora del usuario. Saludos.

Comment: Si, eso es cierto. Estoy seguro que es mejor hacerlo con JS. Gracias por las criticas. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

La zona horaria en tu servidor debe ser configurada pues no se ajusta entonces a la franja horaria en la que te encuentras.

Al inicio de tu script coloca lo siguiente:

```
date_default_timezone_set('aqui_tu_zona_horaria');
```

Donde dice: *aqui_tu_zona_horaria* deberás pasar como argumento un string con el nombre de la zona horaria adecuada, eso [lo puedes consultar aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/es/timezones.php)

Por ejemplo si al momento obtenemos sin configurar una zona horaria personalizada esto saldría en pantalla:

```
C:\Users\user>php -a
Interactive shell

php > print_r(new DateTime());
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2020-07-31 14:50:32.581643
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => UTC
)
php >
```

Por el contrario si le configuro una zona horaria válida este sería el resultado:

```
C:\Users\user>php -a
Interactive shell

php > date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
php > print_r(new DateTime());
DateTime Object
(
    [date] => 2020-07-31 09:50:06.806465
    [timezone_type] => 3
    [timezone] => America/Mexico_City
)
php >
```

Comment: gracias me ayudo mucho