# Quiero recargar un div en php

Tags: php, javascript, div

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "<div id='RefrescarHora'>";
            $fecha=date("H:i:s");
            echo "La fecha del servidor es $fecha";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "La fecha del servidor es $fecha";
    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        setInterval(function(){    
        $( "#RefrescarHora" ).load(window.location.href + " #RefrescarHora" );
        },1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi intención es que se cree dos echo con la misma frase "La fecha del servidor es (Hora)" pero que uno cambie cada segundo y el otro no.

Comment: Te recomendaría que uses `moment.js`  para facilitar esta tarea, es una librería super ligera pero muy útil. [En este fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/speakman/3p9ekp9m/) hay un ejemplo para usar la hora del servidor y pasarla a moment. Y, [en esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/209844/29967) hay un ejemplo simple de moment, pero éste usa la hora del cliente.

Comment: [Aquí hay un ejemplo donde se tomaría la fecha/hora del servidor](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/337086/29967). OJO el snippet no muestra nada en SO porque está bloqueando el acceso al archivo php que puse en línea, pero en tu entorno real debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

veo que estas utilizando jQuery para seleccionar el div RefrescarHora, tienes que incluir la libreria.
Y de resto para la vista te recomiendo que escribas el html puro y en la fecha le coloques la abreviación PHP para echo, quedaria algo asi:

```
<div id="RefrescarHora">
    La fecha del servidor es: <?=date("H:i:s");?>
</div>
<p>
    La fecha del servidor es: <?=date("H:i:s");?>
</p>
```

Saludos